# Get previous displayed output from cmd window

Tags: mysql, windows, cmd

I opened a cmd window and ran a command that I wanted to save. After that, I ran another command and the first output were displaced by the new. is there any way to get the previous result?

The first result was a mysql query result and a scheduled procedure truncated some tables before I could save the log.

Comment: Just scroll up and the previous output will be there. Cmd however discards text past 200 lines by default. You can increase the console buffer size to allow for more lines to remain. Alternatively, you can redirect the output to a file and read from there at your own pace.

Comment: The previous output had 180 lines approx. The new output have 190 lines. I can't redirect the output after I launched the query.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMD, even if you're executing a built-in command such as `dir`. cmd.exe and almost every other console command-line application (e.g. attrib.exe or icacls.exe) write a line of output to the console via `WriteConsole`, `WriteFile`, etc, without keeping a local history. Scrollback history is up to the console host process (conhost.exe), which you can configure to have a screen buffer that's much bigger than the window size (e.g. 9999 lines with a 50-line scrollable view).

Comment: Thanks @eryksun. I generated a dump file and tried to get some information from there. I almost recover everything, but I will consider setting a bigger buffer as default.

Answer (score 0):

On the windows command line I don't think so, you can always try to look up the scroll history but the chances are high that you won't be able to find anything.

You can always try to search for MySQL dumps or in the logs : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-logging.html

I would advice you to use a proper command line as [SecureCRT](https://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/) that allow you to automatically save the logs in a folder.

Comment: Thank you Valentin. Unfortunatelly, I couldn't get all the information, but I was able to recover most of it by a dump file.